# Fingers movement tracing in a video

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Please, I'm trying to detect the fingers' movement in a video. Firstly, I'd like to apply a skin color detection to separate the hand from the background and then I'll find the hand counter followed by calculating the convex points to detect the fingers. What I want now from this video is a new video showing only the movement of the two tapping fingers (or their contour), as shown in this figure.

[image]

I used this code to detect the skin color:

```
  function OutImg=Skin_Detect(I)
  % clear
  % I=imread('D:\New Project\Movie Frames from RLC_L_FTM_IP60\Frame     
  0002.png');
  I=double(I);
  [hue,s,v]=rgb2hsv(I);
  cb =  0.148* I(:,:,1) - 0.291* I(:,:,2) + 0.439 * I(:,:,3) + 128;
  cr =  0.439 * I(:,:,1) - 0.368 * I(:,:,2) -0.071 * I(:,:,3) + 128;
  [w h]=size(I(:,:,1));
  for i=1:w
     for j=1:h            
         if  138<=cr(i,j) && cr(i,j)<=169 && 136<=cb(i,j) && cb(i,j)<=200 && 
            0.01<=hue(i,j) && hue(i,j)<=0.2     
           segment(i,j)=1;            
       else       
            segment(i,j)=0;    
       end    
    end
  end

 % imshow(segment);
 OutImg(:,:,1)=I(:,:,1).*segment;   
 OutImg(:,:,2)=I(:,:,2).*segment; 
 OutImg(:,:,3)=I(:,:,3).*segment; 
 % figure,imshow(uint8(im));
```

The same code is working perfectly when I apply it to an image, but I detect nothing when I apply it to a video, as follows:

```
 videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('RLC_L_FT_IP60.m4v');
 % Create a video player object for displaying video frames.
 videoPlayer = vision.DeployableVideoPlayer;

 % Display the original video
 while ~isDone(videoFReader)
       videoFrame = step(videoFReader);
       % Track using the Hue channel data
        Out=Skin_Detect(videoFrame);
        step(videoPlayer,Out);
 end
```

Please, any suggestion and idea to solve this problem?

I'll be so grateful if anyone can help with this even with different codes.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I think a proper way is using a classifier, even it is a "simple" classifier... Here the steps I have followed in my solution:

**1)** I have used the RGB color space and a Mahalanobis distance for the skin color model. It is fast and work pretty well.

**2)** Connected components: A simple morphological close operation with a small structuring element can be used to join areas that might be disconnected during imperfect thresholding, like the fingers of the hand.

**3)** Feature extraction: area, perimeter, and ratio of area over perimeter, for example.

**4)** Classification: use an SVM classifier to perform the final classification. I hope you have labeled training data for the process.

I am not solving exactly yor concrete problem, but maybe it could give you some idea... :)

Comment: Dear Arritmic thank you so much for your answer but this doesn't solve the problem. I managed to correctly detect the skin within the image but i don't know why it isn't work with the vedio.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on writing on your own, you can use Google's MediaPipe for hand- and finger-tracking.

Info:

https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/08/on-device-real-time-hand-tracking-with.html

Examples for Desktop and Android:

https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/docs/hand_tracking_mobile_gpu.md